# render to a video file that has alpha

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, export, video

I need to have an alpha channel within my movie clips. The problem is, if I render the video with one of settings which were supporting alpha channels my computer and other programs haven't been able to use my video files.

Comment: AFAIK there is no container format (mov, avi) available in blender at the moment, which supports an alpha channel. I'd suggest render an image sequence and encode it afterwards (via ffmpeg for instance) to [prores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ProRes) or [dnxhd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNxHD_codec). Complete list of **production codecs which supporting an alpha channel**: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/17202/6685

Comment: Yes, as Poor says. Export as an image sequence. Use either a PNG or Targa and be sure to select RGBA in the "Output" section of the "Render" panel. If you are using Cycles and lighting with an HDRi be sure to check "Transparent" in the "Film" section of the Render panel. I use After Effects to render out as a .MOV with an alpha channel or Luma Matte.

Comment: EXR, half or full. Please don't use PNG. It is both display referred and suffers from unassociated alpha. Worst. Format. Ever.